# Want to create Android application project with min required sdk of API8

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I do this I receive the error "This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8" but my Android project needs min sdk of API8, how can I manage this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some restriction in version 8 that some default android method or classes you can not use and after that updated version came and that restriction are gone.

So your error clearly say's that you have to use `android:minSdkVersion="14"`. If you want to use `android:minSdkVersion="8"` then you must have to remove some method's or some part of code that is causing this issue.

It's not easy to tell you anything without your code that what actually causing the issue. But by seeing your question and by this line `This template requires a build target API version of at least 14, and the current version is 8` I am pretty much sure that you must have to use `android:minSdkVersion="14"`

Hope this is gonna help you.  Still further if you have any doubt you can comment me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which item was causing the error, but in general you can often get around a minimum API issue by using one of the support libraries. There are several different ones based the desired minimum API and the newer feature wanted. There's a list of libraries and the features they support [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) and some usage instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open **project.properties** file

then set **target=android-21**